# DangerousPhp inside phpseclib when checking with YARA

Tags: php, phpseclib, yara

When doing malware scanning inside the PHP app using [YARA](https://yara.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gettingstarted.html#compiling-and-installing-yara),

> `yara -r ./php.yar -s /myapp`

```
DangerousPhp /myapp/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php
0x1140c:$system: system
0x1083a:$: call_user_func
0x1671f:$: call_user_func
0x154:$: EXEC
```

The malware finder tool used inside is https://github.com/nbs-system/php-malware-finder/

The phpseclib library file that's throwing this error is https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ask the authors of phpseclib, not us. Btw, these functions are not automatically insecure, but could be abused if not handled properly. Afaik there are no known phpseclib exploits..

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Posted here if someone might have experienced a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

False positive. It's unclear what version of phpseclib you're using but let's assume you're using the latest 2.0 release (2.0.34). `call_user_func` only occurs on line 2946:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.34/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L2946

```
                default:
                    if (is_callable($callback)) {
                        if (call_user_func($callback, $temp) === true) {
                            $this->_close_channel(self::CHANNEL_EXEC);
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $output.= $temp;
                    }
```

It's in the exec() method. `$callback` is a parameter who's purpose is discussed at https://phpseclib.com/docs/commands#callbacks . The 3.0 branch does `$callback($temp)` instead of `callback_user_func($temp)` but it's the same basic idea. Probably `$callback($temp)` doesn't work on older versions of PHP whereas `callback_user_func($temp)` does.

`call_user_func_array` is called twice in SSH2.php. Once on [line 2227](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.34/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L2227) and once on [line 3375](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.34/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L3375).

Line 2227 is in the `login` method. Here's what that method does:

```
    function login($username)
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $this->auth[] = $args;

        // try logging with 'none' as an authentication method first since that's what
        // PuTTY does
        if (substr($this->server_identifier, 0, 15) != 'SSH-2.0-CoreFTP' && $this->auth_methods_to_continue === null) {
            if ($this->_login($username)) {
                return true;
            }
            if (count($args) == 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return call_user_func_array(array(&$this, '_login'), $args);
    }
```

In phpseclib 3.0.11 it's doing `return $this->sublogin($username, ...$args);` but the basic idea is that it's taking each element of `$args` and passing it as an individual parameter to `$this->_login`. Like if you did `$this->_login($args)` then `_login` would only be taking a single parameter. [PHP 5.6 introduced the splat (...) operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking) but phpseclib 2 runs on PHP 5.3 so you have to do `call_user_func_array` or just use a single parameter and that's it.

Here's the other instance of `call_user_func_array`:

```
    function _reconnect()
    {
        $this->_reset_connection(NET_SSH2_DISCONNECT_CONNECTION_LOST);
        $this->retry_connect = true;
        if (!$this->_connect()) {
            return false;
        }
        foreach ($this->auth as $auth) {
            $result = call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'login'), $auth);
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

So same thing.

So like I said, this is a nothing sandwich. A false positive.

Comment: Any comment on the error "system"?

Comment: @mujuonly - idk what that's even talking about. The word "system" occurs in the v2.0.34 of SSH2.php 42 times. The vast majority of them are comments. There's also `use phpseclib\System\SSH\Agent`, `const CHANNEL_SUBSYSTEM     = 3;`, `function startSubsystem($subsystem)`, etc. It's about as suspicious as the letter "k" appearing in that file 1,172 times.

Comment: @mujuonly - There is a PHP function named system but phpseclib doesn't call it: https://www.php.net/system My guess is that Yara isn't tokenizing PHP files but is rather just doing a case insensitive string search. Which is of course gonna yield false positives.